# Formatting your questions and answers

Tags: discussion, editing, formatting

Since the first day, I have seen *lots* of posts that don't take advantage of Stack Exchanges formatting options. This makes the question *really* hard to read. So, I have a few suggestions:

- If you are creating a post, please take the time to make it visually appealing i.e. we use a lot of quotes on this site. Make it look like one.
- If you see a post that did not do the above, please take the time to make an edit to make the post more visually appealing. This will only benefit the site.

*This will only benefit the site.* If people who have never seen the site before see poorly formatted posts, they will be less inclined to use our site.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

For help about what Dynamic said look at the top right of the text-entry field when you're posting a question or an answer, you will see a gold circle with a question mark in it.  Click it and it will give you a summery of how to format text, it talks about posting code lists styling/headers etc.  You can also use the [advanced help](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if you need more help, or want to learn more.